# How to save map<String,list<String>> to another map of same type by self checking the values for its key's value

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a map of 'String as key & list of String as value'. I want to check key-value pairs and want the map to self look-up for its new values and make full path of all the combinations. Refer to this image

[image]

I hope this image gives a clear idea as I'm unable to explain this in words. Please help me out in this. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
Map<String, List<String>> sndMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
// Go throuch first map and copy all keys to second map
for (String key : firstMap.keySet()) {
  if (!sndMap.containsKey(key)) {
    sndMap.put(key, new List<String>());
  }
 List<String> tmp = sndMap.get(key);
 tmp.add(firstMap.get(key).get(0));
 sndMap.put(key, tmp);
 } 
 // Go throuch all List of values in first map and check if a value is a key in the second map.  
 for (List<String> values : firstMap.values()) {
   for (String s : values) {
    if (sndMap.containsKey(s)) {
        List<String> tmpList = sndMap.get(s);
        tmpList.add(s);
        sndMap.put(s, tmpList);
    }
  }
}
```